# How to make a question more appealing

Tags: discussion, specific-question

I have been trying to solve a question about modified Takagi functions. I couldn't do it so I asked [this question here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/835933/help-with-modified-takagi-functions) some time ago. First, I included all my work and thoughts but because I didn't get any comments or answers I thought maybe it was too long so then I deleted my work to make the question shorter and therefore easier to read.

But I still didn't get any comments and also not any answers even after offering a bounty.

So, now I am wondering: how can I make a question more appealing? or: why is this question particularly unappealing? And: would it suffice to offer a bigger bounty in the hopes of getting an answer?

Comment: I have long been unsure how much bounties work. The first bounty I posted yielded one answer, which was nothing more than a formalisation of the ideas I said I wanted to improve on and so was rather unsavoury. I think your question looks fine though. Personally, I like stating my questions using box-things (use a " > " before your actual question), as this makes the actual statement stand out more (see my questions for examples). If you think your question is hard enough, and haven't got an answer in another wee while, you could always ask it on [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/).

Comment: @user1729PhD Thank you for your comment. I might post it on MathOverflow eventually.

Comment: Never underestimate the power of good tags on a question. A single real-analysis tag may not grab enough attention. People often have favourite tags which they will skim over, so as long as the tags are appropriate and not too specialised, it's within your interest to add more.

Comment: I think it was just a matter of timing. I answered one question on here that stood for four years without an answer even though it was nothing esoteric. On the Yahoo! Answers math category, if you don't get a first answer within the half hour, you can just forgot about getting any answers even though the questions stand for four days.

Answer (score -8):

Use Latex, it gives the sense of professionality, and also edit it to look orderly much like distinctive paragraphs etc...

Comment: This is good advice in general; but have you looked at the question?

Comment: ah I see..you did get a few comments though so siutiation isn't that bad...maybe general research dosnt foucs on said subject as much..